# Primeng dialog not accessible

Tags: angular, angular-cli, typescript2.0, primeng

I am using  "primeng": "^4.0.0-rc.2" with "@angular/cli": "^1.0.0" and angular4. When I try to use dialog the dialog is not accessible - it is hidden behind the overlay that should prevent access to the remainder of the page. Please see the graphic below

[image]

I expected the dialog to be clickable but the Phone UI to be unclickagle. A snippet of the cod is shown below:

### html

```
 <p-confirmDialog width = "425"
                           class = 'dialog-z-index'></p-confirmDialog>
```

### typescript

```
confirm() {
    this._confirmationSrvc.confirm(
        {
          message: `Are you sure you want to delete the phone entry? ${
              jsonStringify( this.deletionData )}`,
          header: 'Delete Confirmation',
          icon: 'fa fa-trash',
          accept: () => {
          }
        } )
  }

  onDeleteConfirm( event ): void {
    this.deletionData = event.data as IPhone
    this.isDialog = true
    if ( this.isDialog ) {
      this.confirm()
      event.confirm.resolve()
      event.source.onChangedSource.subscribe(
          changedSrc => {
            if ( this.currentData.length < 1 ) {
            }
            else {
            
            }
          } )
      
    }
    else {
      event.confirm.reject()
    }
  }
```

What could be causing this unexpected behaviour?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you need to add this to p-confirmdialog. I've ran into this when working with multiple modals that are active.

```
appendTo="body"
```

Comment: This seems like your solution.

Comment: @user2371215 Worked as you said. Thanks a million. This solution corrected may issues I have been having with primeng dialogs.

Answer (score 0):

I guess You have given two `p-confirmDialog` in Your HTML page. And because you call two `p-confirmDialog` the overlay comes.

So if u delete any one of the `p-confirmDialog` it have to work.

Comment: There is only one p-confirmDialog in the HTML as present above. And only one call to the dialog. Where in my code do you see your inferences?